# Selected row heighlight not working while using alternate row background format

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

i just trying to make cosmetic changes in my grid, which i am using through knockout. 
Following is the my code:

**HTML:**

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tbody data-bind="foreach: frameworks">
    <tr class="rowStyle" data-bind="css: {'selected':$root.selectedItem() == $data , alt: $index() % 2}">
        <td>
            <button class=btn data-bind="click: $parent.doStuff">A</button>
        </td>
        <td data-bind="text: $data"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected
{
background-color:red;
}
.alt {
        background-color: #DBE6F0;
    }
 .rowStyle:hover {
            background: #FFA500;
        }
```

**ViewModel :**

```
var App = new function () {
    var self = this;
    self.frameworks = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
    self.doStuff = function (item) {
        self.selectedItem(item);
        //how to change table row color?
    };
};

 App.frameworks.push('bootstrap');
 App.frameworks.push('knockout.js');
 App.frameworks.push('knockout.js1');
 App.frameworks.push('knockout.js2');
 App.frameworks.push('knockout.js3');
 ko.applyBindings(App);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sunny_DHiman/kbjbmea8/)
In the above code when i select first row then it is highlighted with red color thats good it is same as i want.

**Problem:**

When i select second row then it is not showing selected color. Selected row working on alternate rows.
How i can solve this with all styles which i am using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like an inheritance issue. The alternating row colour is blocking the `.selected` from showing which means you have to give `.selected` more authority than `.alt`. You can chain them or re-order them, CSS cascades so declarations at the bottom take priority over the top, with some special rules/circumstances that can change that slightly.

```
.selected.alt {...
```

or change the order

```
.alt {
    background-color: #DBE6F0;
}
.rowStyle:hover {
    background: #FFA500;
}
.selected
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/

Comment: Change `.selected` to `.selected.alt` :)